# COX throttling my internet connection, anything I can do?

Tags: isp, throttling

So it appears that when cox notices an internet connection using a Bittorrent client, they throttle ALL internet for that customer.  I just got home from being away for a few months, and the first day I was home I was getting download speeds of about 27Mbps (according to http://speedtest.net).  I downloaded a torrent (ironically, it wasn't even an illegal one) three days ago, and ever since, my download speed has been at around 1-2Mbps.  My neighbor, who also uses COX, is still getting 27Mbps.  I also checked out Google's M-Lab and ran ShaperProbe which said my ISP was using shaping and that it was at a rate of almost 20Mbps.  I am hoping that they have just flagged the account or something and it will go back to normal after a few days, but I have a bad feeling that this won't be the case, anything I can do?

Comment: Did you use BitTorrent protocol encryption?

Comment: Unfortunately the newer throttling methods used by Cox and other such awful ISPs is not affected by encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power-cycle your router/firewall and anything else that the packets have to pass through. I thought Verizon was doing this to me, but resetting my Pix firewall always resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't agree with what your ISP is doing, talk to them and ask them to change.  If they refuse, take your business elsewhere.  Your dollar is your most powerful weapon in this battle.

Comment: Unfortunately in my area COX is by the best and cheapest option.

Comment: And by best I mean fastest, but obviously not right now since my bandwidth is being restricted.

Comment: And *that* is the problem with the telco monopolies we have throughout the US.

Answer (score 1):

Does it say that they'll do this in the terms and conditions?

If so then the only thing you can do is change ISP.

If they don't then you could argue that they're engaging in unfair practices, but IANAL so I don't know how far you'd get with that argument.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend resetting your modem/router.  For a long time I thought my provider was throttling me anytime I used bittorrent, then I realized it was that my crappy modem couldn't handle the connection rate.